# How to get last post in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Here is my table structure:

```
// posts
+----+--------------+---------+
| id | post_content | user_id |
+----+--------------+---------+
| 1  | content1     | 65743   |
| 2  | content2     | 24711   |
| 3  | content3     | 45541   |    -- this
| 4  | content4     | 55743   |
| 5  | content5     | 95441   |
| 6  | content6     | 45541   |    -- this
| 7  | content7     | 24711   |
| 8  | content8     | 45541   |    -- this (I want to select this one, Because it is the last one)
| 9  | content9     | 24711   |
+----+--------------+---------+
```

As I've commented in above, I want to get following row, assuming `$user_id = 45541`

```
| 8  | content8     | 45541   |
```

How can I do that in Laravel?

What I've tried so far:

```
$last_post = Posts::where('id', $user_id)->OrderBy('id', 'desc')->first();
```

Comment: And what is not working with your try?

Comment: @u_mulder emm I don't know, I didn't test it yet.

Comment: so what is your issue ?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? That query looks fine. Although `id` is not a good way to order rows by last created

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like so:

```
$last_post = Posts::whereUserId($user_id)->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please modify your query like below:

```
$last_post = Posts::where('id', $user_id)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();
```

Make the order by syntax correct :

```
Change it From :

OrderBy

To:

orderBy
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this one

```
$last_post = Posts::where('id', $user_id)->OrderBy('id', 'desc')->first();
```

to

```
$last_post = Posts::where('user_id', $user_id)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();
```

note : for model name, I think better using singular. Change Posts to Post